# Python Class Initialization and Memory Model Behavior

Tags: python

I know this has been documented somewhere on Stack Overflow, but I can't for the life of me find it... I'll be happy to accept any relevant links.

I have the following code:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x=[]):
        x += [1]
        print id(x), x

print "Try with default:"
a = A()
b = A()
c = A()
d = A()

print "Try with custom:"
a = A([1])
b = A([2])
c = A([3])
d = A([4])
```

Which generates the following output:

```
Try with default:
4342272584 [1]
4342272584 [1, 1]
4342272584 [1, 1, 1]
4342272584 [1, 1, 1, 1]
Try with custom:
4342456688 [1, 1]
4342456688 [2, 1]
4342456688 [3, 1]
4342456688 [4, 1]
```

Why is it when using the default constructor value, the array grows on each subsequent construction?

Comment: The words you're looking for are "Mutable Default Argument". Google it, or read, for example, ["Least Astonishment" in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument).

Comment: Perfect! Those were the words and link I needed. Thanks @agf!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@agf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/500584/agf) came up with the link that answers the question: ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

The accepted response for that link points to the following useful explanation: http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm